# How to use Mechanize on a page with no form?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to write a website crawler with `Mechanize`, and I found that my target website is written in a SPA fashion, and although there are a bunch of text fields and buttons, there is no form!

How can I use `mechanize` to fill text fields and click buttons outside forms?

Comment: You can't. Mechanize does not evaluate JavaScript. Find out what kind of requests result from the button clicks by observing the Network panel in your browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: What does SPA stand for?

Comment: @pguardiario: [Single-Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem you did. I ended up using 'capybara', 'launchy' and 'selenium-webdriver' to  do what 'mechanize' would have in non-JavaScript env

Comment: Thank you for saving my time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `agent` is a `Mechanize` object and `page` is a `Mechanize::Page`.

You can do:

```
form = Mechanize::Form.new page.at('body'), agent
```

Now the form is initialized with all the fields and buttons on the page.

You will need to set the action and method yourself:

```
form.action = 'http://foo.com'
form.method = 'POST'
next_page = form.submit
```